# Why does one have to jump to esp (buffer overflow)?

Tags: buffer-overflow

From what I understand now, since arguments from functions are passed to the call stack, if an argument "overflows" the buffer it is given, it can overwrite the memory after. If enough, it can overwrite the return address which is given to the instruction pointer (eip). Thus, with control to eip, we can send execution to a shell code which has overflowed elsewhere. However, bad characters in shell code are not executed. Why is this, and why do we need to jump to esp and then to the shell code and not directly? Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I understanded it's a normal routine to jump to the esp. The esp is the pointer for the next operation; doesn't the name say it all xD?
The architecture implements that you're using the register for default.

Feel free to correct me too ;D